# Widget XML Android - Need diff dimensions in appwidgetprovider

Tags: android-widget

I have a device that is not displaying my widget properly...it is rendering the minWidth and minHeight in the xml to be a 3x2 and I need it to be a 4x2.  Is there a way to programmatically set these dimensions if a device meets specific dimensions?  It is an MDPI tablet with resolution of 1024 x 720, 160 DPI.

This works on all other devices in my xml (renders as 4x2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_loading_layout"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:configure="com.accuweather.android.tablet.widget.WidgetConfigurationActivity"
    />
```

This works on the abnormal device(renders as 4x2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="368dp"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_loading_layout"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:configure="com.accuweather.android.tablet.widget.WidgetConfigurationActivity"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create another xml folder named: "xml-w1280dp" and in it I have my "normal" rendering code minWidth=294.  This is a nightmare though because it would seem that this is device specific problem...a device should see my xml and know that it is a 4x2 widget, not change it to a 3x2.  The OEM needs to get on board!